# Where are audiobooks accessible in iOS?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, audiobook

I synced an audiobook to my iPhone, now where can I go to listen to it?

I can't find the audiobook in Music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The audiobook can be found in iBooks. For some reason the newly added audiobooks are listed at the bottom of the list after all of the random stuff that is in iCloud.

If you tap "All Books" at the top in the center you can select "Audiobooks" to see only audiobooks.